# How to made MapReduce job always start on master node instead of slave node?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have Hadoop Cluster with 1 master (RAM: 32GB) and 3 slaves (RAM: 16GB).
After I run some MapReduce jobs, I see that sometime my job start on master node, sometime it starts on slave node. With same dataset, job run started on master node run faster than on slave node.

Is it possible to tell Hadoop to always start job on master node instead of slave node?

Thanks!

Comment: It's master/worker.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd Could you please give me more detail? How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do it. At least I have no idea how to make it.